# Can a dynamically linked library override a static one?

Tags: c, ruby, shared-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

`nokogori` gem comes with its own version of `libxml2`. Moreover it [warns](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.10.7/lib/nokogiri/version.rb#L41) about `libxml2.so` of a different version being loaded before it was required:

```rb
      if compiled_parser_version != loaded_parser_version
        ["Nokogiri was built against LibXML version #{compiled_parser_version}, but has dynamically loaded #{loaded_parser_version}"]
```

It basically [compares](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.10.7/ext/nokogiri/nokogiri.c#L78-L85) [`LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlversion.html#LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION) macro and [`xmlParserVersion`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-globals.html#xmlGlobalState) global variable:

```rb
  rb_const_set( mNokogiri,
                rb_intern("LIBXML_VERSION"),
                NOKOGIRI_STR_NEW2(LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION)
              );
  rb_const_set( mNokogiri,
                rb_intern("LIBXML_PARSER_VERSION"),
                NOKOGIRI_STR_NEW2(xmlParserVersion)
              );
```

And I'm experiencing it firsthand. When `rmagick` (which dynamically links to `libxml2.so`, `ldd` confirms that) is required before `nokogiri`, the latter complains.

From what I can see `nokogiri` is linked to `libxml2` statically. First that is [the default](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.10.7/ext/nokogiri/extconf.rb#L475) (supposedly). Then when `rmagick` is not required I can't see `libxml2.so` in `/proc/PID/maps`. I neither can see another version of `libxml2.so`. `ldd` doesn't list `libxml2.so` as a `nokogiri.so`'s dependency. `objdump` lists [`xmlReadMemory`](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory) (and friends) as a `nokogori.so`'s symbol (probably a sign that it was linked statically).

So how come can `nokogiri` access `libxml2.so`'s variables? Does that mean that loading `libxml2.so` overrides any statically linked versions? Can that happen in the middle of code execution?

Comment: I think perhaps you are confusing static linking. Any mention of .so means you are looking at a dynamically linked library, not statically linked.

Comment: @GemTaylor I'm indeed not sure what are sure signs that it's linked statically. But everything suggests that it is. That is, that `nokogiri.so` is linked statically to `libxml2`. And I'm sure that `rmagick.so` is linked dynamically to `libxml2`. Ruby loads `nokogiri.so` and `rmagick.so` when they are `require`d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how come can nokogiri access libxml2.so's variables?

This is by design (and due to the fact that `nokogiri` was built incorrectly).

UNIX shared libraries are *designed* to emulate archive libraries. This means that the first ELF image to export a given symbol wins (there are some complications for libraries linked with `-Bstatic` flag, but we'll ignore them for now).

> Does that mean that loading libxml2.so overrides any statically linked versions?

Yes, if statically linked version is also exported and calls to it go though PLT.

> Can that happen in the middle of code execution?

With lazy symbol resolution (which is default, except when `LD_BIND_NOW` or `-z now` are in effect) it will *always* happen in the middle of code execution.

Now, the problem is that if `nokogiri` links in a static copy of `libxml.a`, it should *hide* that fact by localizing that copy within itself and not exporting any of its symbols. That would prevent end users from having to deal with symbol conflicts.

Your best bet is to either build your own `nokogiri` compiling and linking it against the same version of libxml, or to contact `nokogiri` maintainers and ask them to fix their builds.

Comment: Awesome answer. But can you elaborate please? What are archive libraries? To build correctly one has to add [`-fvisibility=hidden`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43626454/52499)?

Comment: And by any chance do you know a reason why they decided to emulate archive libraries? Also, I've filed a [bug report](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1959). In case you want to correct my phrasing or elaborate on the solution.